# how can I expand a bootstrap well to contain dynamically added content

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Given the markup:

```
<div class="span6">

<div class="well" id="productPanel" >
<img src="http://placehold.it/600x400&text=SELECT RESULTS PLACEHOLDER">
</div>

</div>
```

How can I ensure that the bootstrap well div will expand to contain its contents when I dynamically add image thumbnails to it? Currently, the images overflow the bounds of the well. I need a solution with jquery & or bootstrap **version2** css

An example of the markup which is dynamically added to #productPanel is

```
<ol>
<li title="..." id="prod_123456" class="ui-selectee"><img src="http://whatever.jpg"></li>
<li title="..." id="prod_123456" class="ui-selectee"><img src="http://whatever.jpg"></li>
<li title="..." id="prod_123456" class="ui-selectee"><img src="http://whatever.jpg"></li>
<li title="..." id="prod_123456" class="ui-selectee"><img src="http://whatever.jpg"></li>
<li title="..." id="prod_123456" class="ui-selectee"><img src="http://whatever.jpg"></li>
<ol>
```

Comment: Why don't you apply .well img { width: 100%; height: auto; } ?

Comment: I guess you have a height on your `#productPanel`. wells are only divs with a min-height and a border, and is expanding by default -> http://jsfiddle.net/79qLr/

Comment: @davidkonrad thanks. I forked your fiddle with bootstrap2 http://jsfiddle.net/codecowboy/8UUjm/3/. I am not explicitly setting the height of productPanel but it does seem to be inheriting a height from somewhere.

Comment: @codecowboy: Your forked fiddle works for me in Firefox and Chrome. IE11 was displaying an "access denied" error from jQuery, followed by a "$ is undefined" error. Changing it to use jQuery 1.11.0 fixed the problem, and the well expands as expected.